# jqgrid context menu position left align

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, contextmenu

I'm creating a contextmenu for my grid rows. 
when the menu opens it's position is aligned to the right of the click position.

my page is rtl aligned, so I would like the contextmenu to be as well rtl - so it should open to the left of the click,

How can I change it to be aligned left ?

Thank's In Advance.