# JQGrid dynamic context-menu

Tags: jqgrid, contextmenu

Using JQGrid-4.3.3 with `jquery.contextmenu.js` plugin.

I'm using `onContextMenu` inorder to dynamically show the menu according to a specific cell value inside the selected row. (return true or false).

The problem is after the menu is shown, when I right click another row the menu that was open for the previous row is not closed. If I don't want to show the menu for a row and the menu was opened before , it can't be closed until I show the menu again in another row, or when I left click anywhere in my page.

How can I close the old menu once a `onContextMenu` returns false ?

**UPDATE**:
this is my code:

```
function createGridContextMenu(grid_)
        {                                              
            $("tr.jqgrow" , grid_).contextMenu('grid_contextmenu' , {
                bindings: {
                    'item1': function(trigger)
                    {

                    }                      
                },
                menuStyle: { font:'11px Arial, Verdana, Helvetica', 
                    border: '1px solid #000' , 
                    width: '130px'                                        
                },                     
                itemStyle: {  border: 'none', padding: '4px' }, 
                itemHoverStyle: { backgroundColor: '#C0C0C0', border: 'none'},
                onContextMenu : function(event, menu)
                {          

                    var selected_row_id = $(event.target).parent("tr").attr("id");         

                    var row = grid_.jqGrid('getRowData',selected_row_id);
                    if(row.status == 1)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }                        
                    else
                    {
                        grid_.setSelection(selected_row_id, true);
                        return true;           
                    }
                },
                onShowMenu: function(event, menu)
                {   
                    return menu;                        
                }
            });                           
        }
```

I'm calling `createGridContextMenu` 
inside

```
loadComplete: function()
{
createGridContextMenu($(this));
},
```

Thank's In Advance.

Comment: First of all it's better if you post the code which you use. Do you use `contextMenu` on whole grid or on separate rows? Do you use `bindings`, `onContextMenu`, `onShowMenu`? Which behavior exactly you need to implement? Do you want that the context menu will be closed on `focusout`?

Comment: @Oleg: I've updated my question with my code. I think that this is exactly what I need, that the menu will be closed on `focusout`, How do I implement it? Thank's again!!

Comment: @Oleg: Did you see me question update? is context menu focus out possible ?

Comment: You should just use contextmenu in a little other way. I have little time currently, so I have problem to post you another example of usage contextmenu. I'll try to write the answer on your question later.

Comment: @Oleg: I hope you didn't forgot me :)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the reason of the problem is the wrong place where you create context menu. The second problem is setting **separate** context menus on different rows of the grid.

The callback `loadComplete` will be executed **every time** on loading of the grid, paging, sorting and so on. The current implementation uses `$("tr.jqgrow" , grid_).('grid_contextmenu' , {...});`. On the other side you can set the context menu of the whole `<table>` instead of setting on every `<tr>` of the body of the table. Because `<table>` will be not recreated on every filling of the grid you can do the following

```js
// create the grid
$("#grid").jqGrid({
    ...
});

// set context menu immediately after creating of the grid
// you need remove calling of createGridContextMenu from loadComplete
$("#grid").contextMenu('grid_contextmenu', {
    ...
});
```

I hope that such changes will solve your current problem. I would recommend you additionally to update jqGrid which you use to the current version 4.6.0 which you can download from [trirand](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6).

**UPDATED**: You can hide context menu on leaving it. To do this you can modify [the lines](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.6.0/plugins/jquery.contextmenu.js#L57-L59) 57-59 of the code of `jquery.contextmenu.js` from

```js
.bind('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

to

```js
.bind('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
}).mouseleave(function (e) {
    if (e.pageX === -1 && e.pageY === -1) {
        return; // over tooltip
    }
    hide();
});
```

Alternatively you can do the same *without* modification of `jquery.contextmenu.js`. You need just to do the same *after* calling of `contextMenu`. The final code will be

```js
// create the grid
$("#grid").jqGrid({
    ...
});

// set context menu immediately after creating of the grid
// you need remove calling of createGridContextMenu from loadComplete
$("#grid").contextMenu('grid_contextmenu', {
    ...
});

// register mouseleave handler which close the menu
$("#jqContextMenu").mouseleave(function (e) {
    if (e.pageX === -1 && e.pageY === -1) {
        return; // over tooltip
    }
    $(this).hide().next().hide();
});
```

Comment: Thank's for the answer.I've updated to new jqgrid version. My problem is that I can't create the contextmenu like you wrote beacuse I'm using subgrids, which is being initialized on `subGridRowExpanded`, so the creation of the context menu have to be inside the subgrid loadcomplete. what can I do in this case?

Comment: @user2046810: I think that the example with subgrids will work in the same way. Nevertheless I wrote **UPDATED** part of my answer which should solve you problem.

Comment: I will test it and let you know. thank's for your help!

Comment: maybe you can take a look at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17295062/jqgrid-context-menu-position-left-align], is there somthing I can change  inside `jquery.contextmenu.js` ?

Comment: @user2046810: Sorry, but I'm busy very today and tomorrow. I'll come back to the problem later.